# 400 Bad Request Error while login into app

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, http-status-codes, http-status-code-400

I am running automation script using WebdriverIO and the test case is,

pseudo code:

```
Description("Pay the due payment to the vendor user", async () => {
 it("Pay using CC", async () => {
         Login with Admin
         Perform admit task
         Logout
         Login with approver user
         Approve task
         Logout
         Login with Account user
         perform task
         Logout
      });
  });
```

Login methos is common for all type of user.

Suite opens chrome browser once and multiple times login and logout.

Issue i am facing is that, **Randomly** i am getting 400 bad request error while clicking login button. see reference.

I am capturing Before and after URL of clicking Login button. trying that url manually and it works.

Any idea work wrong with this?

[image]

Comment: We don't have enough information to answer this reliably. The error message hints that sometimes the headers or cookies might be too long, this could happen if you are storing user data in cookies for example, or maybe you enter some sort of loop where the coookie / header is ever growing. Either way, without access to the code / request it is extremely hard to point the issue.

Comment: You might also do a dirty patch by increasing [client_header_buffer_size](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_header_buffer_size) in nginx to accomodate for the large headers, but this is bad practice unless the large headers are _really_ required for the application to function.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I initialising browser in my test case spec file using

```
await browser.url("/");
```

and closing using,

```
 afterTest: async function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {

...
..
..
  await browser.closeWindow();
  await browser.reloadSession();
}
```